# skip multiple values for loop which is passing to a task ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

how can I filter out unwanted values from loop which are passed from register output (from previous task)

code

```
# assume the list_one below register values.
list_one = [root, a, b, c]

- name: with_together
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ list_one }}"
    - "{{ list_two }}"
```

how can I skip only `root` passing to {{item.0}} ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a when condition as below

```
  - name: with_together
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
    when: item.0 != 'root'
    with_together:
     - "{{ list_one }}"
     - "{{ list_two }}"
```